# How to get all posts from the instagram api for a specific user_id?

Tags: instagram, posts

Don't understand how to display all posts. 20 posts displays, and how to bring the rest do not know. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for posting an instagram API on the HTML pages. To allow see Instagram post on the webpages

I have used this before and it working well for me https://lightwidget.com/

Just add your username and details and then they will generate it and you can copy and paste the code into HTML pages.

Answer (score 0):

This API gets a user's page info and last posts:

```
https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1
```

Comment: That only gets the last posts, e.g. 100, what about the rest?